# What does this response mean?

Tags: http, web, client-server, google-developers-console, firefox-developer-tools

This is a response from server of a video file. When seeing the preview in chrome([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGOpe.png)) it shows in some characters(Not sure what kind of character is that. If someone know please let me know what is the name of those characters/symbols). Same video response in firefox([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1J3.png)) is seen as base64. So, is the video is transferred to the browser in form of base64 string even when the content type is set to video/mp4([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAntL.png))? I notice this when i download a pdf file as well. Please explain me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at something that is binary data, not text, therefore it doesn't show as any ascii characters that make any sense.

Comment: but how firefox dev tool show as characters? basically it is showing as base64.